# KeyError when turning list into Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of values I got from the IMDb API. The list is from a dictionary, and the dictionary (defined as `dct`) looks like this:

```
{'data': {'akas': ["Dave 'Gruber' Allen",
   'Dave Gruber Allen',
   "David 'Gruber' Allen",
   'David Gruber Allen',
   'Dave Gruber',
   'The Higgins Boys and Gruber',
   'The Naked Trucker'],
  'birth info': {'birth place': 'Naperville, Illinois, USA'},
  'filmography': [{'actor': [<Movie id:8050858[http] title:_"Ski Master Academy ()" (None)_>,
     <Movie id:7116704[http] title:_"It's a Beach Thing" (2018)_>,
     <Movie id:5016504[http] title:_"Preacher" (2018)_>,
     <Movie id:4847134[http] title:_"Mighty Magiswords (2017-2018)" (None)_>,
     <Movie id:6196406[http] title:_Boy Band (2018)_>,
     <Movie id:4061080[http] title:_"Love (2016-2018)" (None)_>,
     <Movie id:5511512[http] title:_"Trial & Error" (2017)_>,
     <Movie id:2758770[http] title:_"Star vs. the Forces of Evil (2016-2017)" (None)_>,
     <Movie id:5909786[http] title:_"Tween Fest" (2016)_>,
     <Movie id:1289401[http] title:_Ghostbusters: Answer the Call (2016)_>,
...
```

To get everything under `actor`, I input

```
In: dct['data']['filmography'][0]['actor']
Out: [<Movie id:8050858[http] title:_"Ski Master Academy ()" (None)_>,
 <Movie id:7116704[http] title:_"It's a Beach Thing" (2018)_>,
 <Movie id:5016504[http] title:_"Preacher" (2018)_>,
 <Movie id:4847134[http] title:_"Mighty Magiswords (2017-2018)" (None)_>,
 <Movie id:6196406[http] title:_Boy Band (2018)_>,
 <Movie id:4061080[http] title:_"Love (2016-2018)" (None)_>,
 <Movie id:5511512[http] title:_"Trial & Error" (2017)_>,
 <Movie id:2758770[http] title:_"Star vs. the Forces of Evil (2016-2017)" (None)_>,
 <Movie id:5909786[http] title:_"Tween Fest" (2016)_>,
 <Movie id:1289401[http] title:_Ghostbusters: Answer the Call (2016)_>,
 <Movie id:2176287[http] title:_"Comedy Bang! Bang!" (2016)_>,
 <Movie id:2624370[http] title:_"Granite Flats" (2015)_>,
 <Movie id:4574708[http] title:_"W/ Bob and David" (2015)_>,
 <Movie id:4548442[http] title:_Thrilling Adventure Hour Live (2015)_>,
```

The output is just a list. But if I try to turn it into a series with `pd.Series(dct['data']['filmography'][0]['actor'])`, I get an error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here is the code I used to get the dictionary:

```
from imdb import IMDb
import pandas as pd

ia = IMDb()

people = ia.search_person('Dave Allen')
people[0]

dct = ia.get_person_filmography('0020405')
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @DyZ I added some code at the bottom to get the dictionary

Comment: I ran the same code and didn't get any error

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34169848/3180386)'s a some what related question - Which lead me down the path of thinking that the elements in your list are the problem. If you look at the docs, the requirement of a pd.Series is that it takes in an

> array-like, dict, or scalar value

so...  Try this:

```
In [79]: new_list = []

In [80]: for item in dct['data']['filmography'][0]['actor']:
    ...:     new_list.append(str(item))
    ...:     

In [81]: df = pd.Series(new_list)

In [82]: df.head()
Out[82]: 
0            Ski Master Academy ()
1               It's a Beach Thing
2                         Preacher
3    Mighty Magiswords (2017-2018)
4                         Boy Band
dtype: object
```

I too would appreciate a more detailed explanation as to why this happens.  I noticed that your original list elements, when converted to string types in `new-list` actually result in a different 'looking' element.  In fact, when converted only the characters between internal quotes are captured as the `item` in the iterator.  My guess is that the elements of `dct['data']['filmography'][0]['actor']` are somehow not list type elements (?).

#### Updated for Traceback

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    398                         if cls is not object \
    399                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 400                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    401 
    402             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 695     output = repr(obj)
    696     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    697         if idx:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __repr__(self)
     78         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     79         """
---> 80         return str(self)
     81 
     82 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __str__(self)
     57 
     58         if compat.PY3:
---> 59             return self.__unicode__()
     60         return self.__bytes__()
     61 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __unicode__(self)
   1064 
   1065         self.to_string(buf=buf, name=self.name, dtype=self.dtype,
-> 1066                        max_rows=max_rows, length=show_dimensions)
   1067         result = buf.getvalue()
   1068 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in to_string(self, buf, na_rep, float_format, header, index, length, dtype, name, max_rows)
   1108                                         float_format=float_format,
   1109                                         max_rows=max_rows)
-> 1110         result = formatter.to_string()
   1111 
   1112         # catch contract violations

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_string(self)
    257 
    258         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 259         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    260 
    261         if self.truncate_v:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _get_formatted_values(self)
    247         values_to_format = self.tr_series._formatting_values()
    248         return format_array(values_to_format, None,
--> 249                             float_format=self.float_format, na_rep=self.na_rep)
    250 
    251     def to_string(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal)
   1820                         space=space, justify=justify, decimal=decimal)
   1821 
-> 1822     return fmt_obj.get_result()
   1823 
   1824 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in get_result(self)
   1840 
   1841     def get_result(self):
-> 1842         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1843         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
   1844 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1886                 fmt_values.append(float_format(v))
   1887             else:
-> 1888                 fmt_values.append(u' {v}'.format(v=_format(v)))
   1889 
   1890         return fmt_values

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _format(x)
   1868             else:
   1869                 # object dtype
-> 1870                 return u'{x}'.format(x=formatter(x))
   1871 
   1872         vals = self.values

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <lambda>(x)
   1855         formatter = (
   1856             self.formatter if self.formatter is not None else
-> 1857             (lambda x: pprint_thing(x, escape_chars=('\t', '\r', '\n'))))
   1858 
   1859         def _format(x):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/printing.py in pprint_thing(thing, _nest_lvl, escape_chars, default_escapes, quote_strings, max_seq_items)
    220         result = _pprint_seq(thing, _nest_lvl, escape_chars=escape_chars,
    221                              quote_strings=quote_strings,
--> 222                              max_seq_items=max_seq_items)
    223     elif isinstance(thing, compat.string_types) and quote_strings:
    224         if compat.PY3:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/printing.py in _pprint_seq(seq, _nest_lvl, max_seq_items, **kwds)
    116     for i in range(min(nitems, len(seq))):  # handle sets, no slicing
    117         r.append(pprint_thing(
--> 118             next(s), _nest_lvl + 1, max_seq_items=max_seq_items, **kwds))
    119     body = ", ".join(r)
    120 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imdb/utils.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1471         # Handle key aliases.
   1472         key = self.keys_alias.get(key, key)
-> 1473         rawData = self.data[key]
   1474         if key in self.keys_tomodify and \
   1475                 self.modFunct not in (None, modNull):

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't know why that happens or why it results in a keyerror, but converting to str fixed the problem. Thanks much

Comment: Yep - it has something to do with the `<` character (the first character in the list).  I couldn't find anything, so I've added it to my list of things to figure out...